# Swift AVAudioEngine not working as in Apple Documentation

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avaudioengine

I am trying to build a simple mp3 player using `AVAudioEngine`.

I made one using `AVAudioPlayer` and it worked fine (eventually).

I now need to move up to `AVAudioEngine` to give more functionality and I cannot get it to play even a simple file.

I have used exactly the code described in the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudioengine)

And although the app builds (in Playgrounds at present) and prints all the messages to the console that I put in to show progress, nothing can actually be heard.

Here is the code I am using. Most from the Apple notes, but some from other questions I found online.

```
func azAEngine () {
    let audioFile = try! AVAudioFile(forReading:URL(fileURLWithPath:Bundle.main.path(forResource:"bluesuedeshoes.mp3", ofType:      nil)!)))

    let azURL = URL(fileURLWithPath(Bundle.main.path(forResource:"bluesuedeshoes", ofType: "mp3")!))
    
    print(azURL)     
    let audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()    
    let playerNode = AVAudioPlayerNode()    
    
    // Attach the player node to the audio engine.
    audioEngine.attach(playerNode)
    print("Audioengine attached ")
    // Connect the player node to the output node.
    audioEngine.connect(playerNode,                         
                        to: audioEngine.outputNode, 
                        format: audioFile.processingFormat)
    print("playernode attached")
    playerNode.scheduleFile(audioFile, 
                            at: nil, 
                            completionCallbackType: .dataPlayedBack) { _ in
        print("Done")
        /* Handle any work that's necessary after playback. */
    }
    
    do {
        try audioEngine.start()
        playerNode.play()
        print("playernode here ")
    } catch {
        /* Handle the error. */
        print("Failed")
    }
    print("player started") 
}
```

Comment: The engine likely shouldn’t be inside the function it needs to live longer (the length of the sound)

Comment: Gosh...that was a quick answer .. I am amazed at your commitment.  Thank you.  I will try that tomorrow ... Sorry to be a beginner , but where should I put it ? I only have two files: MyApp and ContentView as created by playgrounds.  Thanks in advance

Comment: In the content view

Comment: Brill.  Thank you so much.

Comment: code in line 2 and 4 does not compile. line 2: remove last bracket. line 4: replace bracket after `fileURLWithPath` argument by a colon and remove last bracket. But it would be better to initialize your URL only once..

Comment: Brilliant.  That all works. Thank you both  so much. I really appreciate the way this community operates!. Andy